# call an array method

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this method, and I am trying to call that method doing `[self getUsers ObjectAtIndex:0]` but compiler won't compile that line at all and says it's unknown. How do I call an array method to display all the string in it?

```
- (NSArray*)getUsers
```

{

```
NSArray *getUsers = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSString *databasepath;

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
//NSString *databasePath;

//get the document directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

//build the path to the database file
databasepath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                                  @"users.db"]];

const char *dbPath = [databasepath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
sqlite3 *userdb;

if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &userdb) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = \"%@\"", txtUsername.text];
    const char *sql_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(userdb, sql_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char *field = (char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSString *usernameField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field];
            //NSLog(@"%@", usernameField);
            getUsers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:usernameField];

        }

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

sqlite3_close(userdb);

return getUsers;
```

}

Comment: [[self getUsers] ObjectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[self getUsers] objectAtIndex:0]`.

If you use the latest Xcode/clang version, you can also use `[self getUsers][0]`, since arrays now support indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider say you had a method -(id)someMethod, and then called it like this:

```
id myValue = [self someMethod];
```

Inside someMethod, there is a return statement - whatever is to the right of the return is what will be assigned to myValue in the calling method or function.

Just call like this:

```
NSArray *arrAllUsers = [self getUsers]; //As getUsers is method which returns nsarray.
```